# MetaModelUnstructured Computational Time

Tags: openmdao

I am using sample 2D functions for optimization with MetaModelUnStructuredComp.
Below is a code snippet. The computational time spent for training increases considerably as I increase the number of sample points. I am not sure if this much increase is expected or am I doing something wrong. 
The problem is 2D and predicting 1 output below is some performance time;

```
45 sec for 900 points* 
14 sec for 625 points 
3.7 sec for 400 points
```

*points represent the dimension of each training input

Will decreasing this be a focus of openMDAO development team in the future? (keep reading for the edited version)

```
import numpy as np
from openmdao.api import Problem,  IndepVarComp
from openmdao.api import  ScipyOptimizeDriver
from openmdao.api import MetaModelUnStructuredComp, FloatKrigingSurrogate,MetaModelUnStructuredComp
from openmdao.api import CaseReader, SqliteRecorder
import time
t0 = time.time()

class trig(MetaModelUnStructuredComp):
    def setup(self):
        ii=3
        nx, ny = (10*ii, 10*ii)
        print(nx*ny)
        xx = np.linspace(-3,3, nx)
        yy = np.linspace(-2,2, ny)        
        x, y = np.meshgrid(xx, yy)
#        z = np.sin(x)**10 + np.cos(10 + y) * np.cos(x)
#        z=4+4.5*x-4*y+x**2+2*y**2-2*x*y+x**4-2*x**2*y
        term1 = (4-2.1*x**2+(x**4)/3) * x**2;
        term2 = x*y;
        term3 = (-4+4*y**2) * y**2;            
        z = term1 + term2 + term3;        

        self.add_input('x',  training_data=x.flatten())
        self.add_input('y',  training_data=y.flatten())
        self.add_output('meta_out', surrogate=FloatKrigingSurrogate(), 
                        training_data=z.flatten())
prob = Problem()
inputs_comp = IndepVarComp()
inputs_comp.add_output('x',  1.5)
inputs_comp.add_output('y',  1.5)
prob.model.add_subsystem('inputs_comp', inputs_comp)
#triginst=
prob.model.add_subsystem('trig', trig())

prob.model.connect('inputs_comp.x', 'trig.x')
prob.model.connect('inputs_comp.y', 'trig.y')

prob.driver = ScipyOptimizeDriver()
prob.driver.options['optimizer'] = 'SLSQP'

prob.driver.options['tol'] = 1e-8
prob.driver.options['disp'] = True

prob.model.add_design_var('inputs_comp.x', lower=-3, upper=3)
prob.model.add_design_var('inputs_comp.y', lower=-2, upper=2)
prob.model.add_objective('trig.meta_out')

prob.setup(check=True)
prob.run_model()
print(prob['inputs_comp.x'])
print(prob['inputs_comp.y'])
print(prob['trig.meta_out'])
t1 = time.time()

total = t1-t0
print(total)
```

Following the answers below i am adding a code snippet of an explicit component that uses SMT toolbox for surrogate. I guess this is one way to use the toolbox's capabilities.

```
import numpy as np
from smt.surrogate_models import RBF
from openmdao.api import ExplicitComponent
from openmdao.api import Problem, ScipyOptimizeDriver
from openmdao.api import Group, IndepVarComp
import smt
# Sample problem with SMT Toolbox and OpenMDAO Explicit Comp 
#Optimization of SIX-HUMP CAMEL FUNCTION with 2 global optima
class MetaCompSMT(ExplicitComponent):
    def initialize(self):
        self.options.declare('sm', types=smt.surrogate_models.rbf.RBF)
    def setup(self):        
        self.add_input('x')
        self.add_input('y')
        self.add_output('z')        
#        self.declare_partials(of='z', wrt=['x','y'], method='fd')
        self.declare_partials(of='*', wrt='*')
    def compute(self, inputs, outputs):
#        sm    = self.options['sm'] # seems like this is not needed
        sta=np.column_stack([inputs[i] for i in inputs])        
        outputs['z'] =sm.predict_values(sta).flatten()               
    def compute_partials(self, inputs, partials):   
        sta=np.column_stack([inputs[i] for i in inputs])        
        print(sta)
        for i,invar in enumerate(inputs):
            partials['z', invar] =sm.predict_derivatives(sta,i)

# SMT SURROGATE IS TRAINED IN ADVANCE AND PASSED TO THE COMPONENT AS GLOBAL INPUT
# Training Data
ii=3 # "incerases the domain size"
nx, ny = (10*ii, 5*ii)  
x, y = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(-3,3, nx), np.linspace(-2,2, ny))
term1 = (4-2.1*x**2+(x**4)/3) * x**2;
term2 = x*y;
term3 = (-4+4*y**2) * y**2;        
z = term1 + term2 + term3; 
# Surrogate training
xt=np.column_stack([x.flatten(),y.flatten()])
yt=z.flatten()
#sm = KPLSK(theta0=[1e-2])
sm=RBF(d0=-1,poly_degree=-1,reg=1e-13,print_global=False)
sm.set_training_values(xt, yt)
sm.train()


prob = Problem() # Start the OpenMDAO optimization problem
prob.model = model = Group() # Assemble a group within the problem. In this case single group. 
"Independent component  ~ single Design variable " 
inputs_comp = IndepVarComp() # OpenMDAO approach for the design variable as independent component output
inputs_comp.add_output('x',  2.5) # Vary initial value for finding the second global optimum
inputs_comp.add_output('y',  1.5) # Vary initial value for finding the second global optimum
model.add_subsystem('inputs_comp', inputs_comp)
"Component 1"
comp = MetaCompSMT(sm=sm)
model.add_subsystem('MetaCompSMT', comp)
"Connect design variable to the 2 components. Easier to follow than promote"
model.connect('inputs_comp.x', 'MetaCompSMT.x')
model.connect('inputs_comp.y', 'MetaCompSMT.y')
"Lower/Upper bound design variables"
model.add_design_var('inputs_comp.x', lower=-3, upper=3)
model.add_design_var('inputs_comp.y', lower=-2, upper=2)
model.add_objective('MetaCompSMT.z')

prob.driver = ScipyOptimizeDriver()
prob.driver.options['optimizer'] = 'SLSQP'
prob.driver.options['disp'] = True

prob.driver.options['tol'] = 1e-9
prob.setup(check=True, mode='fwd')

prob.run_driver()
print(prob['inputs_comp.x'],prob['inputs_comp.y'],prob['MetaCompSMT.z'])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are willing to compile some code yourself, you could write very light weight wrapper for the [Surrogate Modeling Toolbox (SMT)](https://github.com/SMTorg/smt). You could write that wrapper to work with the standard MetaModelUnstructuredComp or just write your own component wrapper.

Either way, that library has some significantly faster unstructured surrogate models in it. The default OpenMDAO implementations are just basic implementations. We may improve them over time, but for larger data sets or design spaces SMT offers much better algorithms.

We haven't written a general SMT wrapper in OpenMDAO as of Version 2.4, but its not hard to write your own.

Comment: I added a code snippet to the question where I use the SMT. I have been using SMT like this though not sure if it is the most efficient way. And the reason i wanted to use the MetaModelComps was the automated analytical gradients. I am not sure exactly if this is what is happening in SMT.

Comment: its not the most well documented, but the RMTS surrogate in SMT does have analytic derivatives:
https://smt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_src_docs/surrogate_models/rmts.html
https://github.com/SMTorg/smt/blob/master/smt/tests/test_output_derivs.py

Comment: Thanks i will look into that. Looking at the second code snippet in the question, would you say it is a correct way of making use of SMT ? (for the ''predict_derivative'' surrogates?)

Comment: If you use check_partials and it looks correct, then you should be fine.

Comment: As an update; the error obtained from check_partials is in the order of 1e-1 and 1e-2 
(thus there is a star in the results but i think it is ok). Though there 
are 4 times more function evaluations with FD for reaching to the same optimum. 
I could not interpret this behaviour?
Function eval: 50 vs 12;  Gradient eval: 14 vs 10.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to look into the performance of the `MetaModelUnStructuredComp` using your test case a bit more closely. Though I do notice that this test case does involve fitting a structured data set. If you were to use `MetaModelStructuredComp`(http://openmdao.org/twodocs/versions/2.2.0/features/building_blocks/components/metamodelstructured.html), the performance is considerably better:

```
class trig(MetaModelStructuredComp):
def setup(self):
    ii=3
    nx, ny = (10*ii, 10*ii)
    xx = np.linspace(-3,3, nx)
    yy = np.linspace(-2,2, ny)        
    x, y = np.meshgrid(xx, yy, indexing='ij')

    term1 = (4-2.1*x**2+(x**4)/3) * x**2;
    term2 = x*y;
    term3 = (-4+4*y**2) * y**2;            
    z = term1 + term2 + term3;        

    self.add_input('x', 0.0, xx)
    self.add_input('y', 0.0, yy)
    self.add_output('meta_out', 0.0, z)
```

The 900 points case goes from 14 seconds on my machine using `MetaModelUnStructuredComp` to 0.081 when using `MetaModelStructuredComp`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and the efforts. Even though the sample problem fits for structured data set in my main optimization problem I will be using an unstructured dataset. Therefore i used  that in this case too.